# Unable to convert a PNG image using UIImagePNGRepresentation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, png

I'm writing a function to download a regular PNG file from web server and save it to iPhone Photos album. I don't get any error for my code listed below but UIImagePNGRepresentation doesn't perform the convert at all. All images I got were black. I have to enable "auto-enhanced" under Photos to display those image properly. Any clue what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

```
UIImage *orgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/test.png"]]];
NSData * convertedData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(orgImg);

UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData: convertedData];

// Save Image to Photo Album
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self,  
    @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), nil);
```

Some more details of these two output images, orgImg and img:

If I pass orgImg to UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum directly, I did get the same PNG image hosted on the server. However Photos application on my iPhone displays it as a black image because Photos doesn't enhance PNG format automatically.

As for the img I got after using UIImagePNGRepresentation, the image data has been changed by the method, some meta data such as width/height have been removed from the original image. However Photos app on my iPhone still display it as an all black image.

Both images display properly if I copy them into either Safari or email. I didn't get any problem if I use JPEG in the server side either. Just curious why only PNG format doesn't work.

Comment: did you check if you are getting anything in orgImg? Image is loaded from server or not?

Comment: Why would you even do this? Why not just pass `orgImg` to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`?

Comment: Yes Jason is right,why dont you just pass the orgImg to UIImagePNGRepresentation?
The issue with you case could be you neednot to allocate UIImage.
Try
 NSData*data= [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/test.png"]]] ;

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal: this is not an issue. because i have already tested the above code.it's working fine. i think problem with orgImg in above code.it may not be downloaded correctly from web server.